# Is it bad style for an object to have a method that instaniates itself?

Tags: java, coding-style, program-entry-point

I have an object with a method that reads a file and for each line that is read, it parses the data into an object.

For example:

```
public class test{
     private void processData{
        while((input = bf.readLine()) != null){
             test t = new test();
        }
    }
 }
```

Is it correct to do that in a method rather than the main method? Why or why not?

Comment: I dunno, but this feels like a massive design fail. You seem to be constructing an object purely for the side effects of whatever happens in the constructor.

Comment: Sounds like less a massive design fail than an intermediate step on the way to having two classes...

Comment: There is a fairly common style known as the "factory method" where a static method of your class creates instances, usually using private constructors.  There are various situations where this makes sense.  The "factory" may instead be in a different class, often a superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are few design patterns that creates instance of itself or of inner class (Singleton, Builder, Factory pattern).

I dont think you example is usable, while you can create object outside, but haven't access to your private method.

Example from xdesperadox isn't complete as well. Missing **private constructor** and yes, you have to store instance in private static field for next consequence calls for newInstance() (to return same instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad style to recursively create new objects if that is the best solution for your problem.

Comment: Yeah, ultimately it's whatever works.  There are (relatively rare) situations where this sort of thing (creating an instance of the class in one of its instance classes) makes sense.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm just answering his question as he asked it. He doesn't have a very good example or a concrete problem he's trying to solve in his question, so he gets a "squishy" answer.

Comment: Quite true.  I was just saying that I've done this, but only maybe 3 times.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague but I cannot go into more detail for the problem, and I wanted to generalize it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its ok, 
You can create the instance of class any where.

but for a good practice avoid to create new objects, but you can create object if neccessory.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly calling itself or in other words creating the same type of class you can see during parsing/generating `XML`, `Json` or if your Object represents *tree* of data where each Node can store other Nodes

From your example, since you don't call after `processData`  that can cause to **infinite loop**, its ok.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not because Singleton pattern is just based on this.

```
public static Test newInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance = new Test();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

See singleton pattern for detail.

Comment: This is not really the same case as the example however as this is only ever constructed once, not repeatedly.... but that could just be the example, otherwise for the question by itself this is correct!

Comment: yeah I am aware of that. I just wanted to emphasize there valid cases like that.